# PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied Flask.run()

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask

I am running MacOS X with python 3. The folder and files have 755 but I have also tested it in 777 with no luck. My question is if I have the right permissions why does it not let me run without sudo. Or are my settings incorrect?

```
cris-mbp:ProjectFolder cris$ python3 zbo.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "zbo.py", line 9, in <module>
    app.run(host="127.0.0.1",port=81,debug=True)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 843, in run
    run_simple(host, port, self, **options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/werkzeug/serving.py", line 677, in run_simple
    s.bind((hostname, port))
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied
cris-mbp:ProjectFolder cris$ sudo python3 zbo.py 
 * Running on http://127.0.0.1:81/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
 * Restarting with stat
 * Debugger is active!
 * Debugger pin code: 106-133-233
```

Answer (score 83, accepted):

You're trying to run the app on a [privileged port](https://www.w3.org/Daemon/User/Installation/PrivilegedPorts.html) (81) - if you use a higher port such as 5000 you won't need sudo privileges.

Comment: Thank you, I wasn't aware of privileged ports. Makes sense.

Comment: ***The TCP/IP port numbers below 1024 are special in that normal users are not allowed to run servers on them.***

Answer (score 11):

The "permission denied" error is occurring on the `bind` call;  this has nothing to do with directory permissions.

You're attempting to bind to port 81 (an odd choice), which is a privileged port (one that is less than 1024). This means you need to run it as root.

Comment: Thank you, I wasn't aware of privileged ports. Makes sense.

Comment: _"This means you need to run it as root."_ - In this case, the better advice would be to use a port above 1024. Just so the OP doesn't have to run his web app development server as root.

Answer (score 0):

go to c:\python27\ directory and rigtlcick python.exe and tab to compaitbility and select the admin privilege option and apply the changes. Now you issue the command it allows to create the socket connection.after that run script using python

Comment: Don't you mean Python3?

Comment: question is tagged python3.x

Comment: i have used in python 2.7

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully, this is an OK answer, but you can get around this problem by running Flask as a super-user.
Like this:

```
sudo python3 app.py
```

Or in Windows, just run PowerShell or Command Prompt as administrator and call Python normally.

Comment: sudo doesn't work:-
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "app.py", line 2, in <module>
    from flask import Flask, render_template, request, redirect, flash, send_file
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'flask'

Comment: @xkcd you have to install pip dependicies as sudo too: `sudo pip install flask ...`