# Permission Denied to create file in new directory

Tags: python, flask

I'm working on making a login page with flask and whenever the user logs in for the first time it creates a directory with their ID number so I can save a file they upload to that path. Upon trying to save the uploaded file to that new directory, I get the error
"PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'c:\Users\Zachary\Documents\VSCode_Projects\monday_webapp\app\static\user_data\5'
"

Here's the code of me creating the directory on login

```
str_id = str(current_user.get_id())
                absolute_path = os.path.abspath(__file__)
                if os.path.exists(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(absolute_path) + "\\static\\user_data", str_id)) == False:
                    os.mkdir(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(absolute_path) + "\\static\\user_data", str_id), mode=0o777)
                    os.chmod(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(absolute_path) + "\\static\\user_data", str_id), stat.S_IWRITE)
```

Here is where I attempt to save the file

```
filepath = os.path.join(app.config['FILE_UPLOADS'], uploaded_file.filename)
            str_id = str(current_user.get_id())
            absolute_path = os.path.abspath(__file__)
            if User.is_authenticated:
                os.chmod(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(absolute_path) + "\\static\\user_data", str_id), stat.S_IWRITE)
                uploaded_file.save(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(absolute_path) + "\\static\\user_data\\", str_id), uploaded_file.filename)
            else:
                uploaded_file.save(filepath)
```

If the user is not logged in it uploads the file as it's supposed to and saves it to a different directory. However trying to save it when the user is logged in, to their directory, results in the permission error. Doing dir in user_data shows d----- under mode. I'm not quite sure how to get that folder or file permission to be able to save and have tried as much as I could find in my searching but nothing I've tried has fixed it yet.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PermissionError: \[Errno 13\] Permission denied Flask.run()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38298652/permissionerror-errno-13-permission-denied-flask-run)

Comment: Not really, that seems to be an issue with running flask in general and mine is having permission errors trying to write a file